# ¿Existe una forma para optimizar un código con el ciclo for en R?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código que permite obtener los datos máximos y mínimos de cada día. El dato viene junto a la fecha y hora. Pero se demora más de media hora en ejecutar dicho código, entonces me preguntaba si existe una manera de optimizar el proceso para que no tarde mucho tiempo en ejecutar el código.

```
 #CREO UN NUEVO DATA FRAME PARA INSERTAR LOS NUEVOS VALORES
 tbl_MaxMin = data.frame();
 tbl_toRangos = data.frame();

      for (item in dataSplit) {

     tbl_byday <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
     tbl_byitem <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = 1))
  
   #RECORRO TODAS LAS COLUMNAS
   numColum <- length(item)-1
   for (i in 2:numColum){
    nameCol <- colnames(item[i])
    posMax <- which.max(as.numeric(unlist(item[i])))
    if(is.empty(posMax)){
    valMax <- 'No data'
    fechaMax <- 'NO data'
    }else{
     valMax <- max(item[i],na.rm = TRUE)
    fechaMax <- item[posMax,1]
    }

    posMin <- which.min(as.numeric(unlist(item[i])))
     if(is.empty(posMin)){
     valMin <- 'No data'
     fechaMin <- 'No data'
     }else{
     valMin <- min(item[i], na.rm = TRUE)
     fechaMin <- item[posMin,1]
     }

      tbl_byday<-add_column(tbl_byday, Fecha_Max = fechaMax, Max = valMax, Fecha_Min = fechaMin, 
                            Min = valMin ,.after = NULL)
      tbl_byitem<-add_column(tbl_byitem,Max = valMax, Min = valMin ,.after = NULL)

      }
       tbl_MaxMin <- rbind(tbl_MaxMin,tbl_byday[1,])
      }
```

Comment: Con qué volumen de datos está ejecutándose el código?

Comment: Tengo aproximadamente 250000 filas con 31 columnas.